# SQLAlchemy - execute stored procedure and populate class

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Is there a way to execute a stored procedure and get back a class ? For example if i have :

```
class Event(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'event'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
```

Can I do :

```
db.engine.execute('select * from procedure(?,?)', [param1, param2])
```

and then get back a list of Event ?

Thanks

Comment: I think [this function](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.from_statement) may be useful

Comment: Yes, that worked - please add it as an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done by using the [`from_statement`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.from_statement) function:

```
session.query().from_statement('select * from procedure(:p1,:p2)') \ 
               .params(p1 = 1, p2 = 1).all()
```

Comment: I can only call `from_statement('call some_procedure();')` i.e. using the select like the answer raises me an error.